# How to generate a Google ReCaptcha V2 secure token with PHP?

Tags: php, security, encryption, token, recaptcha

I'm trying to generate a secure token for ReCaptcha V2, as described here:
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/secure_token

Unfortunately, my generated stoken isn't valid and I can't find a way to check why it doesn't work. There is a working Java example ([STokenUtils.java](https://github.com/google/recaptcha-java/blob/master/appengine/src/main/java/com/google/recaptcha/STokenUtils.java)),
but I find myself unable to translate it to PHP.

```
public static function generateSecurityToken($secretKey){
    $stoken = array(
        'session_id' => session_id(),
        'ts_ms' => round(microtime(true)*1000)
    );
    $secretKey = self::pkcs5_pad(hash('sha1', $secretKey), 16);
    $stoken_json = json_encode($stoken);
    $stoken_crypt = self::encrypt(self::pkcs5_pad($stoken_json, 16), $secretKey);
    return $stoken_crypt;
}

public static function encrypt($sStr, $sKey) {
    return base64_encode(
        mcrypt_encrypt(
            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 
            base64_decode($sKey),
            $sStr,
            MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
        )
    );
}

public static function pkcs5_pad ($text, $blocksize) { 
    $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize); 
    return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad); 
}
```

Can anybody provide a working PHP example or point out any obvious mistakes in my code?

Comment: I was going to comment on the use of ECB mode, but [it turns out that Google's implementation does this too](https://github.com/google/recaptcha-java/issues/1). Sigh.

Comment: @alingex if you're able to get a working solution can you post the PHP code? Many thanks because you asked a great question!

Comment: @mikey_w see my answer [#31684672](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31684672/3991313) below for a drop-in solution

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a number of problems in your code. First, your `$secretKey` value is computed as a padded SHA1 hash when the implementation requires the **first sixteen bytes** of the SHA1 hash.

```
$secretKey = substr(hash('sha1', $secretKey, true), 0, 16);
```

Second, you are trying to perform a base64 decode of the secret key, which is not valid here. The second argument to `mcrypt_encrypt()` should be `$sKey`, not `base64_decode($sKey)`.

Finally, as explained in x77686d's answer, you should be using an "URL-safe" base64. That is a variation of base64 that is unpadded and does not use the `+` or `/` characters. Instead, the `-` and `_` characters are used in their places.

ReCaptcha's *secure tokens* are a bit of a pain, honestly. They are insecure and the algorithm is undocumented. I've been in the same position as you and needed an implementation, so I [wrote one](https://github.com/slushie/recaptcha-secure-token) and published it on [Packagist as "slushie/recaptcha-secure-token"](https://packagist.org/packages/slushie/recaptcha-secure-token). I'd recommend using it and/or contributing, if only because of the lack of alternative implementations of this algorithm.

Comment: Your implementation is very helpful, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

[Google's STokenUtils.java example](https://github.com/google/recaptcha-java/blob/master/appengine/src/main/java/com/google/recaptcha/STokenUtils.java) uses `com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding.base64url()` (see [`BaseEncoding`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.html)), and its encoding uses '-' and '_' instead of '+' and '/', respectively.

PHP's `base64_encode` doesn't do those substitutions.  See https://gist.github.com/nathggns/6652997 for a `base64url_encode`, but you'll see that it simply changes '+' to '-', '/' to '_', and trims trailing '='s.

You might have other other problems but I just now fixed this same problem (`ERROR: Invalid stoken`) in a Java version using a homegrown Base64 encoder by doing this:

```
encoded = encoded.replace('+','-').replace('/','_').replace("=","");
```

As a fixed target, try encrypting and encoding this object:

```
{"session_id":"1","ts_ms":1437712654577}
```

with this secret key

```
6Lc0MgoTAAAAAAXFM388zn66iPtjOdQgREfZAgqZ
```

and see if you get this: (note that underscore in the middle!)

```
XlPyYFtyfzmsf5rnRIzyuZ4MZo5GoCSxNcI_wAeOqb18zCxhSM5cYxU8fFerrdcC
```

BTW, simply using that secure token as-is should generate a different error: `ERROR: Stoken expired`.  Make that underscore a slash and you're back to `ERROR: Invalid stoken`!

See also `base64url` on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you provide me with the secret key you've used to generate the example you've given so I can compare the results?

Comment: Now not-so secret key added! :)

Comment: I am facing this exact problem. @x77686d can you clarify the PHP code used to create the create the token generated in your answer? In other words how does the base64_encode function you recommend fit into the bigger picture? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again. I had some additional problems as slushie pointed out, but the example was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static function generateSecurityToken($secretKey){
    $stoken = array(
        'session_id' => session_id(),
        'ts_ms' => round(microtime(true)*1000)
    );


    $stoken_json = json_encode($stoken);
    $stoken_json = str_replace('+', '-', $stoken_json);
    $stoken_json = str_replace('/', '_', $stoken_json);
    $stoken_json = str_replace('=', '', $stoken_json);

    $secretKey = pack('H*', substr(hash('sha1', $secretKey), 0, 32));

    $stoken_crypt = self::encrypt(self::pkcs5_pad($stoken_json, 16), $secretKey);
    return $stoken_crypt;
}

public static function encrypt($sStr, $sKey) {
    $json = base64_encode(
        mcrypt_encrypt(
            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, 
            $sKey,
            $sStr,
            MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
        )
    );
    $sStr = str_replace('+', '-', $json);
    $sStr = str_replace('/', '_', $sStr);
    $sStr = str_replace('=', '', $sStr);
    return $sStr;
}
```