# How to generate a Google ReCaptcha V2 secure token with Perl?

Tags: perl, security, encryption, token, recaptcha

I am trying to use google secure token using perl as described in the link
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/secure_token

However it always throws up that the secure token is invalid.
I checked this link as well but with no success
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478724/how-to-generate-a-google-recaptcha-v2-secure-token-with-php](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/secure_token)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Data::UUID;
use JSON;
use Time::HiRes qw/gettimeofday/;
use MIME::Base64::URLSafe;
use Digest::SHA1  qw(sha1 sha1_hex sha1_base64);
use Crypt::Rijndael;

use constant PUBLIC_KEY  => '...';
use constant PRIVATE_KEY => '...';

my $public_key = PUBLIC_KEY;

print "Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8\n\n";

my $uuid = Data::UUID->new();

my $uuid1 = $uuid->create_str();
my $uuidstr = $uuid->to_string( $uuid );

my $seconds = gettimeofday(); #in scalar context it returns a
my $ms      = int($seconds*1000);

my %hash;

$hash{'session_id'} = $uuidstr;
$hash{'timestamp'} = $ms;

my $json = JSON->new->allow_nonref;
my $json_text = $json->encode(\%hash);
$json_text =~ s/"//g;

my $sha_one = sha1(PRIVATE_KEY);
my $new_secret_key = substr $sha_one, 0, 16;

my $block_size = 16;
my $pad = $block_size - ((length $json_text) % $block_size);
my $append_str = $pad x $pad;

$json_text = $json_text . $append_str;

my $cipher = Crypt::Rijndael->new($new_secret_key, Crypt::Rijndael::MODE_ECB);
my $cipher_text = $cipher->encrypt($json_text);
my $encoded_text = urlsafe_b64encode($cipher_text);

print <<EOT;
<html>
<head>
  <script src='//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="$public_key" data-stoken="$encoded_text"></div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
EOT
```

Can anybody point out any obvious mistakes in my code or suggest some already existing perl code?

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not using the JavaScript library to [render the widget](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display)?

Comment: @MattJacob The javascript library requires a unique key per domain.I wan't to use secure token for recaptcha that's one part.Other I want to do it using perl itself.Thanks

Comment: Have you  tried any of the [modules](https://metacpan.org/search?q=recaptcha) available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started with your code, but ended up with something a bit different. I'm no crypto expert, so I'm not exactly sure why my method works and yours doesn't. But here is what I've got - and it does work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Crypt::ECB;
use UUID::Tiny ':std';
use Digest::SHA1 qw(sha1);
use MIME::Base64::URLSafe;
use Time::HiRes qw(time);
use Math::Round qw(round);

my $uuid = create_uuid_as_string(UUID_V4);
my $t = round(time * 1000);
my $json = '{"session_id":"' . $uuid . '","ts_ms":' . $t . '}';

my $pad = 16 - (length($json) % 16);
$json = $json . chr($pad)x$pad;

my $crypt = Crypt::ECB->new;
$crypt->padding(PADDING_NONE);
$crypt->cipher('Rijndael') || die $crypt->errstring;
$crypt->key(substr(sha1($c->{captcha_secret_key}), 0, 16));
my $enc = urlsafe_b64encode($crypt->encrypt($json));
```

I basically converted [this php library](https://github.com/slushie/recaptcha-secure-token) to rough perl to get this to work.