# Google reCAPTCHA Secure Token in PHP without mcrypt_encrypt

Tags: php, security, encryption, token, recaptcha

I'm trying to generate a secure token for ReCaptcha V2, as described here: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/secure_token

I tryed first the [Slushie librairie](https://github.com/slushie/recaptcha-secure-token), ut he use the php function mcrypt_encrypt() and for some reasons, I can't use it :

```
protected function encryptAes($input, $secret) {
    return mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $secret, $input, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
}
```

I tryed tu use mySQL function AES_ENCRYPT instead :

```
protected function encryptAes( $input, $secret )
{
    $stmt = $this->db_connect->prepare( "SELECT AES_ENCRYPT('" . $input . "', '" . $secret . "') AS encrypt" );
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

    return $result[ 'encrypt' ];
}
```

Wich return an encrypted string than look like Google Secure Token example, but I always have the **ERROR : Invalid stoken**

Does anyone know if there is another **PHP encryption method accepted by Google** for Secure Token ?

Thanks

Comment: I think this will guide you in the right direction, [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478724/how-to-generate-a-google-recaptcha-v2-secure-token-with-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478724/how-to-generate-a-google-recaptcha-v2-secure-token-with-php)

Comment: Thank you for your awnser, I'd seen this post but they use the mcrypt_encrypt function. But finally, I have found what make my secure tokens invalid : the pad() function of Slushie ReCaptchaToken Class. It add some chars to the token and make it invalid...

Comment: Now, I have another problem :) I'm having the ERROR : Stoken expired